# Line intersections with SylvesterJS - Did I break my maths?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, lines

I'm using [sylvester.js](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/) for a math framework, but seem to have either forgotten geometry (likely), or am not using it correct.  I'm trying:

```
var angle = 45;
var line1 = $L([1,1],[Math.tan(angle * Math.PI/180),Math.tan(angle * Math.PI/180)]); //Should be a 45-degree angle
angle = -45;
var line2 = $L([0,0],[Math.tan(angle * Math.PI/180),Math.tan(angle * Math.PI/180)]); //Should be a -45-degree angle
line1.intersects(line2);
//returns false, should be true, I would think?
```

This should create a line through 0,0 at -45 degrees, and another through 1,1 at 45 degrees that intersect, right? Any suggestions?  (Note: I usually use a deg2rad var instead of Math.PI/180, this is purely for example sake)

Comment: does it work if you skip the complicated angle stuff?  line1=([1,1], [0,2]), line2 = ([0,0], [1,1])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the tangent of an angle is equal to the length of the opposite leg over the adjacent leg. In other words, rise over run. Thus, the tangent gives you the slope of the line, not the vector along the line.

[image]

To convert an angle to a vector, use sine and cosine:

```
m⃑ = [cos(θ), sin(θ)]
```

You see this in the formula to convert from polar to Cartesian coordinates:

```
(x, y) = (r * cos(θ), r * sin(θ))
```

Since the magnitude doesn't matter (even if you had a magnitude, `$L` normalizes the vector), leave the "r" out of the equation and you get the equation for **m⃑** above.

Note that for each direction vector in your code, the two components are equal, so the vectors lie on the line y=x; thus they are parallel. You can also show the vectors are parallel because the vectors are scalar multiples of each other. More specifically, since the vectors have opposite direction (the scalar is negative), they are [antiparallel](http://www.iscid.org/encyclopedia/Antiparallel). The reference points (0,0) and (1,1) lie on both lines, so the lines spanned by each vector overlap. Sylvester.js' [`Line.intersects`](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/api/line.html#intersects) returns true only if there's a unique intersection point. Since the two lines intersect everywhere, there's no unique point, and the function returns false.

Comment: Thanks very much, outis!  That now makes sense. I had known that sin and cos were used to get the x,y - but hadn't realized that they would also be used to build the vector. When I update my code to use sin, cos - that returns true. I also see now when inspecting the elements in Chrome debugger how they have the same components and will thus always be parallel. Thanks!

Comment: if I have a point and an angle, is there a way in Sylvester to easily specify that? That was my original goal above.. and I seem to be having trouble getting it just right. I've tried: $L([x,y],[x+(Math.cos(ang)), y+(Math.sin(ang))]) though that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @JayCrossler: Outside of asking for clarification, comments shouldn't be used to ask additional questions. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor well suited) for discussions. If you have additional requirements that aren't yet described in the question, edit the question rather than posting a comment.

Comment: ... If you have questions beyond what you originally asked (which looks to be the case), first check whether the question has already been asked before posting a new question. In this case, you should also read the documentation first. Also, take a closer look at my answer. It already describes what you appear to be asking for.

Answer (score 1):

To define a **vector** from an **angle** you need the following calculation.

```
x = sin(angle)
y = cos(angle)
```

You've done this:

```
x = tan(angle)
y = tan(angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, because I haven't ever done much with sylvester, but since line is a special instance of vector, your problem might be in how things are being defined.  When you define your line2 and anchor it at [0,0], the second point is [-.013, -.013], line2 might be shooting off in the wrong direction to ever intersect with the other line; I'm not sure if the line will be extended both ways.

Comment: Lines in Sylvester - like in math - are infinite.